# Perfect numbers method terminating?

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

I'm writing a method where a user's input will output the corresponding perfect number. For instance, if the user's input is "6" then the output would be "2016." Right now it terminates if you try to put in a number. Thanks.

```
    public static void perfectNumber(){
                System.out.println("Please input a number.");
                Scanner inputPN = new Scanner(System.in);
                int r = inputPN.nextInt();
                for (int n = 1; n > r; n++) {  
                    int spd = 1;
                    for (int d = 2; d <= n/2; d++) {
                        if (spd==n) System.out.print(n); 
                        }
```

Comment: What is your actual problem/question?  It's not clear to me from your description.

Comment: And, _please_, give the complete method.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int n = 1; n > r; n++)
```

Here you say, that the for loop should run as long as n is greater than r.

So it run only if you put 0 or lower as nextInt(), in all other cases it does not run.